# How to determine if field value is an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If this has already been asked before I apologize. I couldn't find it.

I need to loop through a list of fields in an object. I'm using:

```
for (var property in preferences_data.person){
    $("div.item form[name=" + property + "]").addClass('active');   
}
```

Which worked great until the preferences_data.person object got an object as the value for one of the fields. I hoping to find a way to check if the property is an object itself and not use those, or a better way altogether.

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to check if the value is a number or string, and only use those. Like `if (typeof preferences_data.person[property] === "string" || typeof preferences_data.person[property] === "number") { /* Your jQuery code */ }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (typeof preferences_data.person[property] === "object")
```

Comment: Beware that `typeof(null)` is also `"object"`.

Comment: thank you. I'll mark it as answer when it lets me in like 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use typeof for this and check if it's an object.

```
for (var property in preferences_data.person){
   if (typeof property !== 'object') {
      $("div.item form[name=" + property + "]").addClass('active');
   } else {
      //do something else
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking for an object, which can be an object literal, array, and `null` will produce, you could check that the value is a string/number, for example:

```
for (var property in preferences_data.person) {
    var cur = preferences_data.person[property];
    if (typeof cur === "string" || typeof cur === "number") {
        $("div.item form[name=" + property + "]").addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Of course, if you want to still check for objects, you can filter out arrays and `null` by using:

```
var theType = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
```

`theType` will then be "[object Object]", "[object Array]", or "[object Null]" (among possible others). So you could use those, and/or `!== null` for checking against `null`.

Also note that characters in the value may break the attribute selector - you should always quote the value **inside** the selector. So change the selector to this:

```
$('div.item form[name="' + property + '"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
(typeof property == "object")

for (var property in preferences_data.person){
     if(typeof(property) != "object")    {
          $("div.item form[name=" + property + "]").addClass('active');   
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `typeof preferences_data.person[property] === 'object'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the typeof operator to check the property is a string:

```
 for (var property in preferences_data.person){
    if (typeof property === "string") {
        $("div.item form[name=" + property + "]").addClass('active');
    }
 }
```